# Is it advisable to use java strings as only mode of method to method communication

Tags: java, function

We are working on a java project and we have several methods which communicate with each other with each returning a different data type such as arraylist, linked list or hash map etc.. one of my friend wants to convert all the hashmap and arraylist outputs of methods to strings before returning them (hashmaps will convert to a format like a="ball"|c="dog";list will convert to a format like a|b|c) and literally use strings as the medium of communication. Is this advisable.

Edit1: The reason this conversation even happened is because we have methods which might return either a hash or string or list. Personally, I prefer returning them after casting to Object and handling them case by case.

I will try to upload a code-snippet soon.

Comment: Definitely not. Oh my god, just don't do this.

Comment: What are your friend's reasons for wanting to do this?

Comment: Your friend seems to have masochist tendencies.

Comment: "we have methods which might return either a hash or string or list."  _There's_ your problem.  You're asking "If I want to shoot myself in the foot, what's better, a bow and arrow or a sledgehammer?"  The answer is don't shoot yourself in the foot.  Your methods should all return one predictable type.

Answer (score 5):

Communication by plain strings is like reinventing the wheel. There are already many formats of inter-whatever communication (like JSON, XML, &c.).

If you are just communicating between classes or methods in your Java code, then communication by Strings is a *horrible* idea because it robs your code of the essential object-oriented characteristics Java is built on (like polymorphism, inheritance, strong variable types, &c.).

What does the string represent? How is it used? A String representing a name and a String representing a Credit Card number are fundamentally different and the things you can do with them are different.

If you use just a String, you end up making *any* String a valid parameter for your function, which can be very dangerous in some cases.

Long story short, don't rush into ["primitive obsession"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrimitiveObsession).

Answer (score 2):

> Definitely not. Oh my god, just don't do this. – Andrew Williamson
>
> Definitely not. Oh my god, just don't do this. – Andrew Williamson
>
> Definitely not. Oh my god, just don't do this. – Andrew Williamson